# Android app requests WCF service (SerializationException - utf-8 related)

Tags: java, android, wcf, utf-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

Some requests from our Android app to a WCF service results in the following error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an
>   error deserializing the object of type xxx.SaveChangesCommand.
>   '�rg�rden' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Xml.XmlException:
>   '�rg�rden' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. --->
>   System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [E6]
>   at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode.
>
> at
>   System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown,
>   Int32 index)    at
>   System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[]
>   bytesUnknown, Int32 index)    at
>   System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte*
>   pBytes, Char*& chars)    at
>   System.Text.UTF8Encoding.FallbackInvalidByteSequence(Byte*& pSrc,
>   Int32 ch, DecoderFallbackBuffer fallback, Char*& pTarget)    at
>   System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char*
>   chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)    at
>   System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32
>   byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)
>
> ```
> --- End of inner exception
> ```
>
> stack trace ---    at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToChars(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count, Char[] chars, Int32 charOffset)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetChars(Int32 offset, Int32 length, Char[]
>   chars)    at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetString(Int32 offset, Int32
>   length)    at System.Xml.ValueHandle.GetString()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadContentAsString()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadElementContentAsString()    at
>   ReadArrayOfstringFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString ,
>   XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonCollectionDataContract.ReadJsonValueCore(XmlReaderDelegator
>   jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.ReadJsonValue(XmlReaderDelegator
>   jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&
>   dataContract)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String
>   name, String ns)    at
>   ReadSaveShoppingListChangesCommandFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString ,
>   XmlDictionaryString[] )    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonClassDataContract.ReadJsonValueCore(XmlReaderDelegator
>   jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.ReadJsonValue(XmlReaderDelegator
>   jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&
>   dataContract)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name,
>   String ns)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

I have been looking for some similar cases and I found this link: 
[Configuring the .NET WCF UTF-8 deserializer to modify/discard non-shortest form chars instead of throwing an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270256/configuring-the-net-wcf-utf-8-deserializer-to-modify-discard-non-shortest-form) 
 with a possible fix of the error with UTF-8 using non-shortest form - if this is the case here which it looks like to me.

But I don't see why this fix should be necessary, because as stated here: 
https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_overhaul_of_java_utf

> The new UTF-8 charset implementation has been integrated in JDK7,
>   Open JDK 6, JDK 6 update 11 and later, JDK5.0u17, and 1.4.2_19.

When I look at the request I see:

> HTTP_USER_AGENT:Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (**java 1.4**)

but the Android app is compiled with **jdk1.7.0_13**

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Why wote down without a comment??

Comment: I have this exact problem. Finding a fix has been a headache. Adding a bounty to get more attention.

Comment: The string �rg�rden is a clue to where the problem is. I would use Fiddler to trace the response and figure out what's going on.  You can configure Android to use Fiddler as a proxy and you'll be able to see the request and response.  You'll need to test under HTTP because setting up HTTPS requires a trusted certificate and it doesn't always work.

Comment: Additionaly to Fiddler, switch ON WCF tracing logs. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: I fixed it the easy way by changing to rest services with ServiceStack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the XML is not completly in UTF-8 format.
See the '�rg�rden' kind of text might be in the other format that UTF-8.
Like  ISO 8859-1 or something.

So try to encode the text in UTF-8 and it might work :)

Comment: This is correct, I thought Morten was looking to only sanitize so that's why I had the bounty on here, but this is correct. To be specific, you specify the encoding on the entity: StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonStringer.toString(),"UTF-8");